# How do I iterate over form fields angular-way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a form containing many fields, which I need to process one-by-one using some function. You can assume I need to concatenate all fields' values into a string.

The form uses ng-model.

```
<div ng-form="form" ng-submit="submit()" novalidate>
    <input ng-model="ctrl.firstName" required="true">
    <input ng-model="ctrl.lastName" required="true">
    <!-- 30+ more inputs -->
</div>
```

I would like to do this angular-way, without iterating over the DOM.

Comment: why cant you just take values of firstname and lastname in controller?

Comment: @Sajeetharan because I have 30+ fields and I want to loop over them rather than tying all their names

Comment: See [AngularJS ng-model Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) and [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this on angular submit function:

```
for (var field in $scope.ctrl) {
    if ($scope.ctrl.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
        // do stuff
        $scope.ctrl[field] ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Even better, in case you have other properties or methods on the controller that you don't want to iterate over, you can namespace all form values in the controller-- something like `$scope.form.lastname`, `$scope.form.firstname`, etc.